# How to distinguish an iframe with the same origin from iframe with different origin

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I have 2 iframe on my webpage. **iframe S** has the same origin as the web page, **iframe D** has a different one:

```
<iframe src="https://mdn-samples.mozilla.org/snippets/html/iframe-simple-contents.html" title="iframe example 1" width="400" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

I need to addEventListener only onto the iframes that have the same origin. This is what I do:

```
for (let i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
    const iframe = window.frames[I]
    console.log(iframe)        
    if (iframe.document.domain === window.document.domain) {
        iframe.addEventListener('message', event => {
            console.log(event.data)
        }, false)
    }
}
```

But this gives an error, when I try to read iframe.document of **iframe D**.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Because, unlike **iframe S**, **iframe D** gives me this object, when I try **console.log(iframe)** from the 2 snippet of code above:

[image]

And as you can see, there is no document property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply select all `iframe`s using `querySelectorAll`, then construct a new [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) using their `src` attribute and check if it matches your own `hostname`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('iframe').forEach(frame => {
  const url = new URL(frame.src)

  if (url.hostname === window.location.hostname) {
    frame.addEventListener('message', event => {
        console.log(event.data)
    }, false)
  }
})
```

```html
<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://google.com"></iframe>
```

Note that `new URL` won't work in IE browsers. You'd have to manually split your URL parts to do the `hostname` equality check.

Answer (score -1):

Wrapping an entire if-statement with with **try - catch block** rids of the error, but not sure if that's the best way to tackle this problem.

```
for (let i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
    const iframe = window.frames[I]
    console.log(iframe)
    try {        
        if (iframe.document.domain === window.document.domain) {
            iframe.addEventListener('message', event => {
                console.log(event.data)
            }, false)
        }
    }
    catch(error) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not an `if` instead of a `try.. catch`?

Comment: How would you construct it? I tried if (iframe.document) and if (iframe). The first one is ridiculous because that accessing .document causes the error, the second one does not divide re-route iframe D to the else block.

Comment: Check the `src` attribute of the `iframe` perhaps?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Same issue. I don't think we are allowed to access any prop of iframe D whatsoever.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The `iframe` is part of *your* DOM.